# Update multiple NULL values using the NON-NULL value available in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables that store two sets of ID's which are the same, when any of the four ID's are NULL there's an issue on the front end application. These four values always vary as to which can be NULL but there will always be one with the correct entry.

My question is can I enter these four values into a temp table then update all the NULL values using the column which has actually has a value? As the column with the correct value changes all the time it makes it harder.

Basically i'm making a stored proc but can't figure this logic out.

Comment: Can you add some sample data of what you have, and an example of the data you want?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to use `coalesce` to find the non-NULL value.

```
coalesce(table1.col1, table1.col2, table2,col1, table2.col2)
```

The only caveat is that if two columns have different non-NULL values, then this expression returns the first one (in the order you list the columns) it finds.  But if you don't have that situation occur, or if you can specify which column you'd use when it does occur, this should work regardless of what combination of columns has NULL.

Comment: How would you specify a column preference? Would you use an IF statement ?

Comment: You would list the preferred column first in the call to `coalesce()`.  So if `col1` and `col2` both have non-NULL values, `coalesce(col1, col2)` will return the value form `col1` but `coalesce(col2, col1)` will return the value form `col2`

Comment: Thanks for your time Mark. I ended up putting the coalesce value into a variable and created a loop to update the tables on a row by row basis from the temp table. Can't see how the Coalesce function would be very useful in other scenarios, i mean unless you store the value in a variable it's not even easy to reference. Thanks again Mark.

Answer (score -1):

Using table expression to join two tables then from the result table, update the column missing data with the ones have.